# command to append a string in a file

Tags: sed

I want to change a remote file. For this i use sed command.
I have file with following content:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=/ankur
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

So I want to append in this file.
I have tried this command:

```
sed -i 's+^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX.*+GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=/sharma+g' '/etc/default/grub.bak'
```

But it changed to value of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX. But I want to append sharma to it initial value.

So the sed command should give the below output for the above file.

expected output:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=/ankur sharma
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Also, please join us in the most basic language agreements, like capitalisation and the easy forms of punctuation. The editor here is much more powerful and does not restrict you to SMS speech.

Comment: Please try: `sed -i 's+\(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX.*\)+\1 harma+g' '/etc/default/grub.bak'`

Comment: like this one if change value of field GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT from  "console" to "console sharma"  in general terms i want to append in double qoutes

Comment: so command should able to do :

Comment: EXpected output:  GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console sharma"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=/ankur sharma
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

Answer (score 5):

Could you please try following simple `sed` once. Please use `-i` option in case you want to place output into Input_file itself.

```
sed '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/s/$/ sharma/'  Input_file
```